# How to make Swagger recognize @XmlTransient (e.g. not ignore it)

Tags: java, rest, jaxb, jackson, swagger

It seems `Swagger` ignores `JAXB` annotations such as `@XmlTransient`

In addition Swagger seems to parse getters as well, ignoring `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)`

is there a way to specify to `Swagger` to respect `JAXB` annotations?

*UPDATE*

code example

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

import com.wordnik.swagger.annotations.ApiModel;
import com.wordnik.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty;

    @XmlRootElement
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @ApiModel( value = "aaa")
    public class A implements IA
    {
        @ApiModelProperty( value = "bla", required = true )
        @XmlElement(name="a")
        private String a;

        @XmlTransient 
        private B b;

         private A() {}//JAXB

         @XmlTransient
         public boolean isC() { return true;};
}
```

interface IA has no annotations. and no getters to field b that might interfere.

swagger generated JSON is:

```
"A": {
      "id": "A",
      "description": "aaa",
      "properties": {
        "c": {
          "type": "boolean"
        }
      }
    }
```

As seen Swagger ignore the fields and `@XMLAccesorType` (as noted by Webron in his answer)
But also ignores JAXB annotation (`@XmlTransient`) on the `isC()` getter function

Comment: Which version of swagger-core do you use? Do you use it directly or as a dependency of another library (such as swagger-springmvc, spray-swagger)?

Comment: swagger-jersey-jaxrs_2.10 v1.3.10

Comment: Does the field/method have any additional annotations on them? Can you edit the question and provide a sample model class?

Comment: updated the question per your request

Comment: UPDATE: when one moves to swagger 2.0 specification. JsonIgnore works. XmlTransient doesnt...

Comment: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/960

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked for me when I've changed versions.
E.g. It works on swagger-jaxrs_2.10 v 1.3.6

Note that it didn't work on swagger-jaxrs_2.10 v 1.3.0
 or on swagger-jeresy-jaxrs_2.10 v 1.3.10...

At least now `@JsonIgnore` and `@XmlTransient` are being respected

Comment: Note that in the comment to your question you mentioned you're using 1.3.10 which is later than both mentioned here.

Comment: yes, this didn't work for me when I used swagger-jersey-jaxrs_2.10 v1.3.10, I then shifted to swagger-jaxrs_2.10 and there I used 1.3.0. Still didn't work. Then I moved to 1.3.6

Comment: rephrased the answer to support the comments discussion

Answer (score 1):

With my tests, that sample just doesn't work. Since there are no public accessors nor public fields, the swagger-core introspection does not work properly altogether.

Once I added accessors to `a` only, it produced a model with only the `a` field.

If the field is private, and has no accessors, it will not be included in the model whether `@XmlTransient` exists or not. With accessors, `@XmlTransient` works just fine.

Keep in mind that swagger-core does not (currently) process `@XmlAccessorType`.

I suspect that sample is incomplete and doesn't allow me to further investigate.

Comment: I have edited the sample to add a private Ctor. Jackson (and gson) are able to serialize

Comment: I have edited the sample to add a private Ctor. Jackson (and gson) are able to serialize\deserialize the class.
if Swagger doesn't process XmlAccessorType this means it will always look for getters. Howevever even if I mark isC() with xmltransient it is not respected

Comment: That code won't even compile. I need a full-working test case. Hiding information doesn't help. Provide a full class with implemented interfaces, if there are, and the resulting output. Without it, I'm just shooting in the dark.

Comment: changed the code to compile and also posted JSON generated by Swagger. I apologize for earlier version, tried to manually obfuscate a working example.

Comment: Again, that gives me a completely different output. Do you use Java 8? If so, does your interface have any default methods? Try it yourself, take that code **as is**, remove the interface (as you say it adds nothing) and see the output yourself.

Comment: what is pasted is an actual try. live. nothing manual. I use Java 7. It's weird you get a different output. What is the output u get?

Comment: I don't even get a valid model introspection since everything is private and/or annotated with @XmlTransient.

Answer (score 0):

For swagger users in 2019, simply use the swagger annotation `@Hidden` with `@XmlTransient` on top of your methods:

```
@XmlTransient
@Hidden
public getFoo(){
...
```